# DBCC PAGE equivalent in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-11

In SQL Server you could check specific index information using the `DBCC PAGE` command. Is there anything similar in postgres?

And if there isn't, how would you get the same info then? This is simply for research purposes.

This command returns this:

```
Page @0x00000004ED67A000

m_pageId = (1:299)                  m_headerVersion = 1                 m_type = 1
m_typeFlagBits = 0x0                m_level = 0                         m_flagBits = 0x4
m_objId (AllocUnitId.idObj) = 121   m_indexId (AllocUnitId.idInd) = 256
Metadata: AllocUnitId = 72057594045857792
Metadata: PartitionId = 72057594040614912                                Metadata: IndexId = 1
Metadata: ObjectId = 99             m_prevPage = (1:297)                m_nextPage = (1:300)
pminlen = 4008                      m_slotCnt = 2                       m_freeCnt = 70
m_freeData = 8118                   m_reservedCnt = 0                   m_lsn = (35:184:44)
m_xactReserved = 0                  m_xdesId = (0:0)                    m_ghostRecCnt = 0
m_tornBits = 0                      DB Frag ID = 1

Allocation Status

GAM (1:2) = ALLOCATED               SGAM (1:3) = ALLOCATED 
PFS (1:1) = 0x60 MIXED_EXT ALLOCATED   0_PCT_FULL                        DIFF (1:6) = CHANGED 
ML (1:7) = NOT MIN_LOGGED

Slot 0 Offset 0x60 Length 4011
```

Comment: What information does this return in SQL Server? Is [pageinspect](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pageinspect.html) something similar or maybe [amcheck](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/amcheck.html)?

Comment: added picture to show the output @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: so what is that information? What does it tell you that you want to know about indexes in Postgres?

Comment: for example stuff like `m_prevPage` and `m_nextPage` show which pages are before and after the current page you're looking at (horizontally not vertically, talking about btree structure) `m_freeCnt` for example shows how much space is not used in that page etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can

```
CREATE EXTENSION pageinspect;
```

Then you can use the function

```
SELECT * FROM bt_page_stats('indexname' , 42);
```

to get some information about block 42 of the index: the number of live and dead entries, the amount of free space and the pointers to the left and right sibling (`btpo_prev` and `btpo_next`) and the type (`r`oot, `i`ntermediate or `l`eaf).

Comment: How do you get the block numbers?

Comment: You start with `bt_metap()` to get the root page and proceed from there.